# PHP SQL On update remove previous column data from other rows with same name

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
id | job_no | comment | status | current_status
------------------------------------------------
1  |  9201  |  ...    | active | active
------------------------------------------------
2  |  9201  |  ...    | hold   | hold
------------------------------------------------
3  |  9201  |  ...    | cancel | cancel
------------------------------------------------
```

When I enter a comment for a job no 9201 in this example, and change status to cancel for example, I need the column status to update as 'cancel', and current_status to update as 'cancel', but all previous rows for job 9201 current_status to update to blank ('') and status remain as was. Like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
id | job_no | comment | status | current_status
------------------------------------------------
1  |  9201  |  ...    | active |
------------------------------------------------
2  |  9201  |  ...    | hold   |
------------------------------------------------
3  |  9201  |  ...    | cancel | cancel
------------------------------------------------
```

So, every time I update, status updates for that id, but current_status only to update the last id for that job_no and other rows with that job_no current_status to be blank.

Been struggling for days now... Please help.

This is all done on one page with a page refresh at the end. Someone enters a comment, it appears at the bottom of the page and current_status at top of the page changes:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO history (user,comment,job_no,status)
VALUES ('$user','$comment','$job_no','$status')";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $insert) or die 
(mysqli_error($connection)); 

$sel_query="Select * from history ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$status = $row['status'];
$job_no = $row['job_no'];
}

$update1="update history set current_status='$status' where 
job_no='$job_no'";
mysqli_query($connection, $update1) or die(mysqli_error());   


echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
```

Comment: Can we see what your query looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question and added my queries.

Comment: do you have any restrictions on using sql triggers?

Comment: I can use triggers, I dont see any limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First, update all the rows with `current_status = ''` for supplied `job_no`

```
UPDATE history 
SET current_status = ''
WHERE job_no = "$job_no"
```

and then update the last one with `current_status = 'cancel'`:

```
UPDATE history 
SET current_status = 'cancel'
WHERE job_no = "$job_no"
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can get id and job_no from the row you want to change status.

So you can simply update this one by id :

```
UPDATE HISTORY
SET status = 'cancel', current_status = 'cancel' 
WHERE id = 3;
```

Then update all others with this id + job_no

```
UPDATE HISTORY
SET current_status = '' 
WHERE job_no = 9201 AND id != 3;
```

[working db-fiddle example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7erCVVB5uLExJZ866HCjfb/0)

Comment: Why are you adding a check of `id != 3`. table can have any number of entries for that particular job id.

Comment: Here it's not job_id but job_no ; id looked like the primary key of the HISTORY table. By definition an id is unique and so the table cant have multiple entries with same id.

Comment: How did you know that 3 is the latest id? You either need to find the max id in a separate `select` query and then use it in queries you wrote.

Comment: I think he never said that the change of status could only be done on the last id...

Comment: Please check his question again. It's not that clear but try to understand what he asked for `current_status only to update the last id for that job_no and other rows with that job_no current_status to be blank.`